# Regex for matching between 2nd quotation and file name?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a powershell script that opens up CSV files and replaces 2nd column full file path with just file names. I am able to use -replace function in powershell, but I don't have a way to explicitly match certain string because the file path vary in lengths and how many sub directories there are.

I need help in using regex to match the string like this:

String: `"1003,"\\ST12345\share$\SYSTEM\V1\1\2\1234.htm"`

I want to match: `\\ST12345\share$\SYSTEM\V1\1\2\`

so I could replace the above with empty (thus delete it). Another issue is the shares could have vary number of directories, so there could be 2 back-slashes or there could be 4 backslashes, but there will always be a file name and the string will always start with \.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `"\\ST12345\share$\SYSTEM\V1\1\2\1234.htm" | Split-Path -Parent`

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` and check/modify the value of the respective column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question exactly as asked (even though your input string has an imbalanced `"`):

```
PS> '"1003,"\\ST12345\share$\SYSTEM\V1\1\2\1234.htm"' -replace '(?<=")\\.+\\'
"1003,"1234.htm"
```

- `(?<=")` is a look-behind assertion that matches the `"` immediately before the file path without including it in the match.
- `\\.+\\` matches an (escaped) `\` followed by any nonempty sequence of characters (`.+`) followed by a `\`. .NET regex matching is *greedy* by default, so everything through the *last* `\` is matched, effectively removing the file's directory path.

Comment: @user2242057: Glad to hear it helped; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following pattern:

```
(?<=,").*?(?=\d+\.htm)
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/oVYDCg/1).

---

Powershell demo:

```
$matches = '"1003,"\\ST12345\share$\SYSTEM\V1\1\2\1234.htm"' | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=,").*?(?=\d+\.htm)'
$matches.Matches.Value
```

Prints:

```
\\ST12345\share$\SYSTEM\V1\1\2\
```

Comment: You're an amazing person. Thank you!

Comment: @user2242057 You are welcome :) @Bill, when I tried split-path as you suggested the result contained `1003,` too

Comment: Not if you use `Import-Csv` (recommended), rather than parsing individual lines (as noted by Ansgar Wiechers).